# Are there flight tours over Antarctica?

Tags: air-travel, tours, antarctica

There used to be air tours of Antarctica flown by Air New Zealand but unfortunately they have stopped after a crash of a [Air New Zealand flight 901](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_New_Zealand_Flight_901).

Are there any plans to resume such tours?  By either Air New Zealand or any other airline.  Or are there such tours in existence already?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certainly. Qantas flies them from Australia.

[Antarctica Flights](http://www.antarcticaflights.com.au/)

They're infrequent, but a few a year do fly down.  I watched a documentary on it, it's crazy that you can pay less for an 'inner' seat where you don't even get to see out the window without craning your neck!

From the site:

> The flight provides a full day of Antarctic experience. Our flight
>   from Australia ranges between 9,500 – 10,500 kms roundtrip
>   (approximately 12.5 hours) depending on your departure city. Expert
>   Antarctic expeditioners are onboard to talk on the polar environment
>   and its history while video screenings depict life on the ground.
>   Approximately three hours south of Australia, passengers will usually
>   see the first scattered ice followed by dozens of icebergs and ice
>   floes. We then cross the South Magnetic Pole where you will start to
>   view the rugged mountainous topography of the Antarctic mainland.

Comment: Whilst it's correct to say that Qantas flies them, they are actually run by Croydon Travel (now apparently under the brand "Antarctica Flights") who charter a plane from Qantas for the flights.